# Sql - one or two databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, database-schema

I want to ask a question that can only be answered through experience.

I'm creating a SQL database (finance) - it uses an entity framework.

The database can be broken into two distinct parts:

1. (the applicant) - personal details, address, contact data and
   the applications made;
2. (the processing) - lenders, time taken to
   process, commissions paid etc.

The two parts can be connected via the ApplicationId, which is also used as the TransactionId in #2.

However, the two parts serve two very different purposes:

Part 1 - a record of the customers application (likely to be stored for at least 6 years) and used to service the customer;

Part 2 - internal stats/analysis (likely to be stored for much less time and subject to more change over time).

First thought was to build a single database (linked via the ApplicationId), but I'm now not sure it's the right approach. Queries made on each part are unlikely to cross over and in the rare instance it would take a couple of lookups instead of one.

With that in mind, would it be a more sensible long term approach to split it into two parts - or two models?

This is a question about practicality rather than large database sizes or model complexity.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer here. And it is nearly impossible to have a solid opinion based on such little information.

Comment: I agree with you Sean but as I pointed out from the outset, it's a decision made easier with experience (which I have not).

Comment: You are correct. But this is considered off topic for SO. And even it was on topic it is impossible to answer because there are almost no details provided. Maybe simply using 2 schemas would work? Maybe you are completely overthinking this and you just need a single database (my guess)? Or maybe what you need is an analysis cube that is populated with daily data movement? Who knows?

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer a single database, because as you said the data will be reference on bouth parts. If your analysis data starts to became too larger you can migrate them to a Olap base, but you are just stating the application, so i don't see what you will benefit from two data bases. If you want to separete then from a point of organization you can always put then on diferents scheamas... partOne.clients and partTwo.Data

Comment: Any time you say "I prefer..." as an answer just proves the question is opinion based, which makes it off topic for this site. So thanks for your contribution, but this question should be closed and not answered.

Comment: @DavidG - may I remind you that this is my question and not Rodrigos, and I have no 'preference' other than I'd prefer you not to force your own opinions on others.

Comment: @John Your question is off topic for Stack Overflow, that's not an insult, it's just how the site works.